# Center letter in p-tag with pixel-defined width and height

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a circle with a number in it:

This is my current approach:

```
<p class="count">1</p>
```

Css:

```
.count{
background: #002244;
color: white;
font-size: 32px;
border-radius: 25px;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px 18px;
}
```

It creates a round p-tag with a background-color using border-radius.
It works fine in principle, but the problem is that in order to center the letters, the padding needs to vary some from browser to broswer, due to font-rendering i think.

Does anyone know a better method to achieve this where the letters will be centered without defining the pixel-count?

Comment: try line-height. If you give line-height same as height, it will be vertically centered. Works with single lines. Don't forget to remove paddings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use padding to adjust the location of the text, use `line-height`

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M95q2/)

```
.count{
background: #002244;
color: white;
font-size: 32px;
border-radius: 50%; /* use percentage instead of px value */
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height:50px; /* same as element height */
}
```

Comment: it doesn't really center it inside the circle. The center of the text-line is not in the same place as the center of the circle.

Comment: Looks good to me. I'm not sure I can understand what, other than the above, you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, that looks great, something else has to be the problem!